# Form Submit from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I want to Submit a Form from controller in Laravel.

I know I can use guzzle to send HTTP POST request to update/add data.

But I want to go to that external .NET CORE Project URL with some data with post request that returns a view.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   // Append some secret data to request

   // Form submit to external url
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Guzzle is the right tool for this.

Comment: @ceejayoz Guzzle will just receive response behind the scenes. I want to redirect to action url with data

Comment: well thats almost only choice you can still receive a response with a html data and parse it

Comment: @TEFO Thank you for your response.But I need to do in that way

Comment: @AsifSultan I need a million dollars, but that's not going to change the fact that I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel HTTP client for that, https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-client

```
public function store()
{
    return view('view',[
         'response' => Http::post(...)
    ])
}
```

Comment: That's just a simpler API for Guzzle, which OP has already rejected.